# Unsupported Media Type during image uploading in .NET microservices

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, microservices

I have a .NET microservice e-commerce application and am having issues when I add image uploading to the CreateProduct. At one point it did work, but reverting to that commit doesn't restore functionality. I have a BaseClass.cs that makes all the calls to the APIs and my breakpoints on the actual API's controller POST methods never gets reached now. I'm handling it with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and will paste the BaseClass code and the ProductAPI controller code below. Can anybody provide some insight on what can fix this? Everything I've found on Google, etc. over the past week hasn't helped so I'm desperate.

```
    public class BaseService : IBaseService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
    private readonly ITokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BaseService"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientFactory">Factory for creating instances of <see cref="HttpClient"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="tokenProvider">Provider for retrieving authentication tokens.</param>
    public BaseService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, ITokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Asynchronously sends an HTTP request based on the provided <see cref="RequestDto"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requestDto">The request data transfer object containing request details.</param>
    /// <param name="withBearer">Indicates whether to include a bearer token in the request header.</param>
    /// <returns>A task that represents the asynchronous operation. The task result contains the <see cref="ResponseDto"/>.</returns>
    public async Task<ResponseDto?> SendAsync(RequestDto requestDto, bool withBearer = true)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a new HttpClient instance with a named configuration from the IHttpClientFactory
            HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("MicroAPI");
            HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage();

            // Set the Accept header based on the ContentType defined in the request DTO
            if (requestDto.ContentType == ContentType.MultipartFormData)
            {
                // Add support for multipart/form-data for file uploads
                message.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            }
            else
            {
                message.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            }

            // Include bearer token in the request if required
            if (withBearer)
            {
                var token = _tokenProvider.GetToken();
                message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }

            // Set the request URI and content
            message.RequestUri = new Uri(requestDto.Url);

            if (requestDto.ContentType == ContentType.MultipartFormData)
            {
                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                foreach (var prop in requestDto.Data.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    var value = prop.GetValue(requestDto.Data);
                    if (value is FormFile)
                    {
                        var file = (FormFile) value;
                        if (file != null)
                        {
                            content.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream()), prop.Name, file.FileName);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        content.Add(new StringContent(value == null ? "" : value.ToString()), prop.Name);
                    }
                }

                message.Content = content;
            }
            else
            {
                if (requestDto.Data != null)
                {
                    message.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestDto.Data), Encoding.UTF8,
                        "application/json");
                }
            }

            HttpResponseMessage? apiResponse = null;

            // Set the HttpMethod based on the ApiType defined in the request DTO
            message.Method = requestDto.ApiType switch
            {
                ApiType.POST => HttpMethod.Post,
                ApiType.PUT => HttpMethod.Put,
                ApiType.DELETE => HttpMethod.Delete,
                _ => HttpMethod.Get
            };

            // Send the HTTP request asynchronously
            apiResponse = await client.SendAsync(message);

            // Handle different HTTP status codes
            switch (apiResponse.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                    return new ResponseDto {Message = "Not Found", IsSuccess = false};
                case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
                    return new ResponseDto {Message = "Forbidden Access", IsSuccess = false};
                case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                    return new ResponseDto {Message = "Unauthorized", IsSuccess = false};
                case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                    return new ResponseDto {Message = "Internal Server Error", IsSuccess = false};
                default:
                    var apiContent = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var apiResponseDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseDto>(apiContent);
                    return apiResponseDto;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Log the exception details for debugging purposes
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Inner Exception: {e.InnerException.ToString()}");
            }

            // Return a response DTO indicating the failure
            ResponseDto dto = new() {Message = e.Message.ToString(), IsSuccess = false};
            return dto;
        }
    }
}

ProductService class

    using Micro.Web.Models;
using Micro.Web.Service.IService;
using Micro.Web.Utility;

namespace Micro.Web.Service;

public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private readonly IBaseService _baseService;

    public ProductService(IBaseService baseService)
    {
        _baseService = baseService;
    }

    public async Task<ResponseDto?> GetProductAsync(string productCode)
    {
        return await _baseService.SendAsync(new RequestDto()
        {
            ApiType = ApiType.GET,
            Url = SD.ProductAPIBase + "/api/product/GetByCode/" + productCode,
        });
    }

    public async Task<ResponseDto?> GetAllProductsAsync()
    {
        return await _baseService.SendAsync(new RequestDto()
        {
            ApiType = ApiType.GET,
            Url = SD.ProductAPIBase + "/api/product/",
        });
    }

    public async Task<ResponseDto?> GetProductByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _baseService.SendAsync(new RequestDto()
        {
            ApiType = ApiType.GET,
            Url = SD.ProductAPIBase + "/api/product/" + id,
        });
    }

    public async Task<ResponseDto?> CreateProductAsync(ProductDto productDto)
    {
        return await _baseService.SendAsync(new RequestDto()
        {
            ApiType = ApiType.POST,
            Data = productDto,
            Url = SD.ProductAPIBase + "/api/product",
            ContentType = ContentType.MultipartFormData
        });
    }

    public async Task<ResponseDto?> UpdateProductAsync(ProductDto productDto)
    {
        return await _baseService.SendAsync(new RequestDto()
        {
            ApiType = ApiType.PUT,
            Data = productDto,
            Url = SD.ProductAPIBase + "/api/product",
            ContentType = ContentType.MultipartFormData
        });
    }

    public async Task<ResponseDto?> DeleteProductAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _baseService.SendAsync(new RequestDto()
        {
            ApiType = ApiType.DELETE,
            Url = SD.ProductAPIBase + "/api/product/" + id,
        });
    }
}

ProductController

    using Micro.Web.Models;
using Micro.Web.Service.IService;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Micro.Web.Controllers;

public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService;

    public ProductController(IProductService productService)
    {
        _productService = productService;
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> ProductIndex()
    {
        List<ProductDto>? list = [];

        ResponseDto? response = await _productService.GetAllProductsAsync();

        if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
        {
            list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProductDto>>(Convert.ToString(response.Result));
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["error"] = response?.Message;
        }

        return View(list);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> ProductCreate()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProductCreate(ProductDto model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ResponseDto? response = await _productService.CreateProductAsync(model);

            if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
            {
                TempData["success"] = "Product created successfully";
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(ProductIndex));
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["error"] = response?.Message;
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> ProductDelete(int productId)
    {
        ResponseDto? response = await _productService.GetProductByIdAsync(productId);

        if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
        {
            ProductDto? model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductDto>(Convert.ToString(response.Result));
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["error"] = response?.Message;
        }

        return NotFound();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProductDelete(ProductDto productDto)
    {
        ResponseDto? response = await _productService.DeleteProductAsync(productDto.ProductId);

        if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
        {
            TempData["success"] = "Product deleted successfully";
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(ProductIndex));
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["error"] = response?.Message;
        }

        return View(productDto);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> ProductEdit(int productId)
    {
        ResponseDto? response = await _productService.GetProductByIdAsync(productId);

        if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
        {
            ProductDto? model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductDto>(Convert.ToString(response.Result));
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["error"] = response?.Message;
        }

        return NotFound();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProductEdit(ProductDto productDto)
    {
        ResponseDto? response = await _productService.UpdateProductAsync(productDto);

        if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
        {
            TempData["success"] = "Product updated successfully";
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(ProductIndex));
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["error"] = response?.Message;
        }

        return View(productDto);
    }
}

ProductCreate view

    @model ProductDto

<form asp-action="ProductCreate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br/>
    <div class="container border p-3">
        <h1 class="text-white text-center">Create Product</h1>
        <hr/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label class="control-label pt-2" style="font-size:20px;"> Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 pb-3">
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <label class="control-label pt-2" style="font-size:20px;">Category Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 pb-3">
                <input asp-for="CategoryName" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="CategoryName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <label class="control-label pt-2" style="font-size:20px;">Description</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 pb-3">
                <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <label class="control-label pt-2" style="font-size:20px;">Price</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 pb-3">
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <label class="control-label pt-2" style="font-size:20px;">ImageUrl</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 pb-3">
                <input asp-for="Image" class="form-control"/>
                <input asp-for="ImageUrl" hidden class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 offset-2">
                <a asp-action="ProductIndex" class="btn-primary btn form-control ">Back to List</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial"/>
}
```

[image: Debug info]

Comment: It seems that the issue is on the called side. Have you checked what has changed there?

Comment: Try decorating the `ProductDto` with `FromFormAttribute`. Like so `ProductCreate([FromForm]ProductDto model)`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you'd like to post image file(s) with additional data through `FormData` from your MVC app to ASP.NET Core API backend, please check if you apply [`[FromForm]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#sources) to your API action parameter to specify the source.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    //...

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromForm]ProductDto model)
    {
        //your code logic here
        //...
```

*not applying `[FromForm]` attribute to parameter, which cause same issue like below.*

[image]